# Gracefully handling checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have some javascript that I am currently working on that checks for the existence of a check in a check box. This javascript code is more or less horribly written and we do the check multiple times in multiple places in the code to see if the check box was checked or not. I am asking if there is a graceful way to set a master override for check box options that only gets checked once to both improve performance and to keep the code DRY. Basically right now for every place that it needs checked I go to

```
if($("#element").attr("checked")){ 
    do something... 
} else {
    do something else...
}
```

I'm a bit of noob with javascript so I was wondering about this more as a best practice question.

Comment: You're going to need `()` around `("#element").attr("checked")`

Comment: Are the mistakes non-intentionnal? : `if($('#element:checked').length>0){/*do something*/}else{/*something else*/}`  **NEVER FORGET THE $ SIGN**

Comment: When you say you do this multiple times, does it mean there are multiple forms on a single page? Can you provide more info on how the webpage works

Comment: What is this meant to do? Iterate over, and check, *every* checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get all the checkboxes that are checked on the current page and then iterate through them.

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");

for (var i =0; i<checkedBoxes.length; i++)
{
   //do something
}
```

This only works for FF 3.1+, Safari 3.1+, **IE8+** and Chrome 4+

Also note that querySelectoAll returns a **NodeList**(not an Array).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a specific checkbox is selected:
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TesUq/

```
if($("#element").is(":checked")){ 
    console.log('#element is checked');
} else {
    console.log('#element is not checked');
}
```

---

If you want to check which checkboxes are selected:
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TesUq/1/

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log($(this).prop('id') + ' is checked');
    } else {
        console.log($(this).prop('id') + ' is not checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to see if ANY checkbox is checked:

```
if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
    /* do whatever you need to do */
}
```

For specific checkbox handling:

```
var chkBox = $('input:checkbox');
$.each(chkBox, function(i, v) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        /* do whatever for this specific element using $(this) *\
    };
});
```

Comment: `this.checked` does the same thing as `$(this).is(':checked')`, but does it faster, and less expensively.

Comment: @DavidThomas   Thanks, I did not know that. Typically, I program for consistency. What I start with jQuery, I like to finish with jQuery - rather than popping back and forth between jQuery and raw JS. That's just me. PS. What kind of savings are we talking about?

Comment: To be entirely fair, it's *minimal* (though I'm surprised at how minimal it is, I think perhaps I've not set the test up properly, though): [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/checkboxes-are-checked-testing-with-js).

Answer (score 0):

You can track the state yourself to reduce the time spent doing jQuery selects...

With this HTML

```html
<div>
    <label for="box1">Box 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="BoxOne" />
    <span>Checked:</span>
    <span id='box1state'>?</span>
</div>
```

and this javascript

```js
$('document').ready(function () {

    var box1state = $('#box1state');

    $('#box1').change(function (e) {
        box1state.text(this.checked);
    });

    box1state.text($('#box1')[0].checked);
});
```

(see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/uQv5y/1/)

The `<span>` will always contain the current state of the checkbox.
This technique could instead be used to test the state of the checkbox and `do something...` or `do something else...` within the `.change(...)` function.  Each time the checkbox state changes and *only* when it changes the code gets fired to do what you want.